# Set tax status to none by default on new product creation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm working with Woocommerce and have setup taxes for products. But most of the products won't be taxable, only a few ones.

Creating a new product will set the tax status to Taxable by default. In my situation, I would prefer to have this tax status set by default to None and change the status only when needed, since almost all new products won't be taxable.

I have been looking around but didn't find any reference to this specific issue. I suppose that would need custom code to change that.

Any help or clue here would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that will set the stock status as "None" by default when creating a new product on page load:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_tax', 'new_product_tax_status_none');
function new_product_tax_status_none()
{
    global $post, $pagenow;

    // Only on new product pages
    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // On load set the tax status to none
        $('select[name="_tax_status"]').val('none');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thanks a lot LoicTheAztec, it does work indeed. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @LoicTheAztec ! works perfectly. I edited it in order to set only the delivery as taxable by default. This is it:

```html
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_tax', 'new_product_tax_status_shipping');
function new_product_tax_status_shipping()
{
    global $post, $pagenow;

    // Only on new product pages
    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // On load set the tax status to shipping
        $('select[name="_tax_status"]').val('shipping');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```